# create mx Tree from a custom XML

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

i have a custom XML, i want to create a mx Tree from that xml, it looks like this one :

```
  <Saa:Header>
        <Saa:Message>
            <Saa:SenderReference> data
             </Saa:SenderReference>
       </Saa:Message>
        <Saa:Message>
            <Saa:SenderReference> data
             </Saa:SenderReference>
       </Saa:Message>
  </Saa:Header>
```

and

```
                    <mx:Tree id="myTreetest"
                     width="100%"
                     height="98%"
                     horizontalCenter="0"
                     labelField="@label"
                                    />
```

the script should be :

```
myTreetest.dataProvider = new XML(?);
```

Comment: are you asking how to load the xml?  Is your xml above in an xml file next to your application?  or is assigned to variable in your code?  A String from some other source?

Comment: yes how to load the xml into the tree ! is an xml string from a WS